# error in using atoi in string to int conversion

Tags: c++

So, I try to use atoi function to convert a string to int, however I got an error saying that argument type char is incompatible with parameter of type const char*. here is the code:

```
void evaluate(const char values[], string& codeMessage, string& result)
{
    unsigned int i = 0;
    while (i<codeMessage.length())
    {
        result+= values[atoi(codeMessage[i])];
        i++;
    }
}
```

so, if the function `evaluate({a,b,c,d}, "2331", result)` is called, the result have to contain `"cdda"`. any idea, what's wrong w/ my code? thx

Comment: `atoi` expects a string, not a character.

Comment: error in using documentation to find out how to use library functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`atoi` expects a C-string, not a single character.

If you want to lexically convert a digit to the equivalent integer, why not simply assert that it's between `'0'` and `'9'`, then subtract `'0'`? Numbers are required to be consecutive regardless of the locale's character set.

```
while (i < codeMessage.length()) {
    if (codeMessage[i] >= '0' && codeMessage[i] <= '9') {
       result += values[codeMessage[i] - '0'];
    }

    i++;
}
```

Comment: what does "codeMessage[i]- '0'" means? subtracting a character with character 0?

Comment: @user1988385, If the character is `'4'`, it will be 4 spots ahead of `'0'` in the encoding. As such, subtracting `'0'` will give 4.

Comment: It's the character `'0'` subtracted from the character `codeMessage[i]`. [Subtraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtraction) is when you take one number away from another number, e.g. 5-3=2. `char`s are just numbers underneath, and we can perform arithmetic on those underlying values.

Comment: It's the number `codeMessage[i]` minus the number `'0'`. Both C and C++ require that the numbers represented by the values `'0'` through `'9'` increase by one as you go along, so that you can always subtract `'0'` from a value that represents one of those integers and get the corresponding numeric value.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, You can use `std::transform`, too: http://liveworkspace.org/code/OeDYw%242

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, In the spirit of not reinventing the wheel and all. You know :)